# Trim "-" from data returned from SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, trim, character-trimming

I have a query that in SQL Server that returns data like this:

```
1234-A
2345-BB
3456-C
5678-CC
4567-AA              
6789-B
01234-A
26857-ZZ
```

This is what I need it display:

```
A
B
C
C
A
B
A
Z
```

I need to get the first letter behind the '-'. How do I get this to display?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE (MyCol VARCHAR(255));
INSERT @MyTable (MyCol)
VALUES ('1234-A'),('2345-BB'),('3456-C'),('5678-CC'),
       ('4567-AA'),('6789-B'),('01234-A'),('26857-ZZ');

SELECT SUBSTRING(MyCol, CHARINDEX('-', MyCol, 1) + 1, 1)
FROM @MyTable;
```

`CHARINDEX` finds where the '-' in the column value is.
`SUBSTRING` starts at that index + 1 and returns, in this case, 1 character.

Comment: @Scratte See my update.  You can also look at the docs, this is pretty trivial t-sql.  I made up my own schema since OP didn't include one.

Answer (score -1):

You can use substr In conjunction with instr to get the output

Comment: That looks like functions from Oracle, while the question is about SQL Server.